# Как запретить переход на предыдущую страницу?

Tags: php, javascript, yii

Как обнулить предыдущую страницу?
Хочу запретить пользователю использовать кнопку "Назад" в браузере.

Comment: \Yii::$app->user->setReturnUrl(null) Вы об этом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

решение не мое

```
history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    history.go(1);
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/RgDBQ/show/

взято отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182993/how-to-prevent-a-browser-from-going-back-forward-in-history-when-scrolling-horiz

Comment: Вы не перетащили из оригинального ответа упоминание, что от перехода к конкретному пункту в истории и долбления по кнопке "Назад" этот трюк не спасёт. Всё-таки важная информация.

Comment: кнопка назад не работает же. проверил в фф и хроме. ну а про выбор страницы из истории думаю не всякий догадается. а удалять историю в браузере я вряд ли смогу

Answer (score 2):

Если вы про запрет на нажатие кнопки "Назад", то вы не можете это сделать: ни со стороны сервера, ни со стороны клиента.

Если вы не хотите, чтобы пользователь возвращался, то есть несколько "решений":

1. Если действие, после которого пользователь не должен иметь возможности вернуться — это "разлогиниться", то при попытке вернуться пользователь получит страницу с предложение залогиниться. Это нормально.
2. Вы можете перетащить логику перемещений по страницам на `history.replace`, которая заменяет текущую запись в истории и не создаёт новой. Если страница одна, то и возвращаться некуда.

В целом, если ваш сайт реализован корректно, то необходимость в подобных действиях избыточна.

Answer (score 0):

найдено на просторах интернента

```
window.onload = function() {
if (typeof history.pushState === "function") {
    history.pushState("jibberish", null, null);
    window.onpopstate = function() {
        history.pushState('newjibberish', null, null);
        // Handle the back (or forward) buttons here
        // Will NOT handle refresh, use onbeforeunload for this.
    };
        }
else {
    var ignoreHashChange = true;
    window.onhashchange = function() {
        if (!ignoreHashChange) {
            ignoreHashChange = true;
            window.location.hash = Math.random();
            // Detect and redirect change here
            // Works in older FF and IE9
            // * it does mess with your hash symbol (anchor?) pound sign
            // delimiter on the end of the URL
        }
        else {
            ignoreHashChange = false;
    }
    };
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    removeBack();
});
function removeBack(){
    history.pushState(null, null, '');
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
        //тут какие то другие действия пишем если надо 
        history.pushState(null, null, '');
    });
    };
}
```